# Flexlayout does not work with command and command parameter

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am being trying to use the flexlayout and it's great but now for each item in the stack layout i need to add tapped gesturer,command etc..

Whatever I try does not work.The only thing that works is the stacklayout.TapGestureRecognizer but as soon as I try to use the command does not work.

I even tried the https://taubensee.net/adding-touch-events-to-flexlayouts/
and added a commandparameter bindable property but does not work either.

How do you add a command with commandparameter to flexlayout .below is my code

```
  <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
                                         AlignContent="Start"
                                         AlignItems="Start"
                                         Direction="Row"
                                         JustifyContent="Start"
                                         Wrap="Wrap">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout                            
                        FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Start"
                        FlexLayout.Basis="50%">
                        <!--<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>-->
                        <Frame>
                            <!--<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>-->
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="whatever"></Label>
                                <!--<Image Source="myimage.png">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" CommandParameter="AAAA"
                                                              NumberOfTapsRequired="1"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>-->
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <!--<FlexLayout.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:FlexLayoutItemTappedBehavior
                    Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand2}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
            </FlexLayout.Behaviors>-->

        </FlexLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, which is the version of forms and VS .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT  vs 2019 XF 4.0.0.618610

Comment: Okey, I have updated a solution for reference.If works let me know.

Comment: I have tested in Xamain.forms 4.1 and VS 2019, it works.You can have a try with updating Xamarin.Forms .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FlexLayout** maybe miss the touch events and commands , have a try with **Behavior** to realize it.

Create a new class that inherits from `Behavior<T>`:

```
public class FlexLayoutItemTappedBehavior : Behavior<FlexLayout>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(FlexLayoutItemTappedBehavior), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty ParamaterProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Paramater), typeof(object), typeof(FlexLayoutItemTappedBehavior), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get => (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public object Paramater
    {
        get => (object)this.GetValue(ParamaterProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(ParamaterProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(FlexLayout bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

        if (bindable.BindingContext != null)
        {
            this.BindingContext = bindable.BindingContext;
        }

        bindable.BindingContextChanged += this.OnFlexLayoutBindingChanged;
        bindable.ChildAdded += this.OnFlexLayoutChildAdded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(FlexLayout bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);

        bindable.BindingContextChanged -= this.OnFlexLayoutBindingChanged;
        bindable.ChildAdded -= this.OnFlexLayoutChildAdded;

        foreach (var child in bindable.Children)
        {
            if (child is View childView && childView.GestureRecognizers.Any())
            {
                var tappedGestureRecognizers = childView.GestureRecognizers.Where(x => x is TapGestureRecognizer).Cast<TapGestureRecognizer>();
                foreach (var tapGestureRecognizer in tappedGestureRecognizers)
                {
                    tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped -= this.OnItemTapped;
                    childView.GestureRecognizers.Remove(tapGestureRecognizer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnFlexLayoutBindingChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is FlexLayout flexLayout)
        {
            this.BindingContext = flexLayout.BindingContext;
        }
    }

    private void OnFlexLayoutChildAdded(object sender, ElementEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Element is View view)
        {
            var tappedGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tappedGestureRecognizer.Tapped += this.OnItemTapped;

            view.GestureRecognizers.Add(tappedGestureRecognizer);
        }
    }

    private async void OnItemTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is VisualElement visualElement)
        {
            var animations = new List<AnimationBase>();
            var scaleIn = new ScaleToAnimation
            {
                Target = visualElement,
                Scale = .95,
                Duration = "50"
            };
            animations.Add(scaleIn);

            var scaleOut = new ScaleToAnimation
            {
                Target = visualElement,
                Scale = 1,
                Duration = "50"
            };
            animations.Add(scaleOut);

            var storyBoard = new StoryBoard(animations);
            await storyBoard.Begin();
        }

        if (sender is BindableObject bindable && this.Command != null && this.Command.CanExecute(null))
        {
            object resolvedParameter;
            if (Paramater != null)
            {
                resolvedParameter = Paramater;
            }
            else
            {
                resolvedParameter = e;
            }
            if (Command.CanExecute(resolvedParameter))
            {
                this.Command.Execute(bindable.BindingContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, in order to use this `Behavior` from `XAML`, you can reference it like this:

```
<FlexLayout.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:FlexLayoutItemTappedBehavior
        Command="{Binding NavigateToDetailCommand}" Paramater="{Binding .}"/>
</FlexLayout.Behaviors>
```

About **Reusable EventToCommandBehavior** , you can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior#creating-the-behavior) .

Comment: Jiang I have done that too but when the command fires there is no commandparameter I even added the command parameter binding to a property but  nothing. I the current suggestion how do you know which item you clicked?

Comment: @developer9969 Yeah , this can not know which be clicked.

Comment: @developer9969 If want to add command parameter in this solution, need to add 
Paramater `BindableProperty` for `FlexLayoutItemTappedBehavior`.

Comment: @Jiang fantastic help still not resolved but I am moving on.